# Leave blank entries, if field has date, insert text

Tags: excel, if-statement, office365, excel-2013

I have a columns of 200+ entries from A-1 to column AF-1. On the last two columns, I want to set a reminder if there is a date field entered on the left, and the words "Past Due" on the far right column.

I've tried researching this formula by using "IF" commands. The formulas below work in my spreadsheet:

```
=IF(AE10<TODAY(),"PAST DUE","")
```

-OR-

```
 =IF(AE14"<"(TODAY()+7),"PAST DUE","")
```

I don't want to setup fictitious dates of 1/1/2050 in order for the right column to be blank but can if I have to.

Some rows do not have follow-up dates so they are blank. I would like the blank cells to the left column, remain blank on the right column.

If there is a date, I would like the phrase "Past Due" to show in the right column. I will then use conditional formatting to highlight those cells with "Due" text in them.

I have tried:
`=IF= () OR (working formula)`
`=IF(BLANK(AE10)...`
`=IF(AE10="","",=DATEDIF(AE10,TODAY(),"d"))`

Comment: Yes, the formula only needs to work on columns AE (left) and AF (far right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, you just need to wrap your formula in another `IF()` function. Try this: `=IF(AE10="","",IF(AE10<TODAY(),"PAST DUE",""))`

Comment: No problem. Can you please mark this as answered? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to "upvote" your answer but it said my reputation was too low.  I've only recently joined this user forum.